# How to convert my data into a format suitable for d3.js sunburst?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have a data like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L79wjn0x/, and I would like to convert it in this format https://jsfiddle.net/49n1jmL5/. I am trying to make use of `d3.nest` method to change the format but unable to make it work. In my data children are linked with parent through parents'id.

Sample data I have is like below. Children are linked with parent 
through parent's id that is children's `parent_id` key is same that of 
parent's id key.

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ab",
    "parent_id": null,
    "value": 120,
    "tree_level": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ac",
    "parent_id": null,
    "value": 110,
    "tree_level": 1
  } {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "abc",
    "parent_id": 1,
    "value": 30,
    "tree_level": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "abcd",
    "parent_id": 1,
    "value": 90,
    "tree_level": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "abc",
    "parent_id": 3,
    "value": 10,
    "tree_level": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "abc",
    "parent_id": 3,
    "value": 20,
    "tree_level": 3
  }
]
```

and i would like the above json format to be converted like below format. 
Can anyone lead me to the correct way

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ab",
  "parent_id": null,
  "value": 120,
  "tree_level": 1,
  children: [{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "abc",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "value": 30,
      "tree_level": 2
      children: [{
          "id": 5,
          "name": "abc",
          "parent_id": 3,
          "value": 10,
          "tree_level": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "abc",
          "parent_id": 3,
          "value": 20,
          "tree_level": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "abcd",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "value": 90,
      "tree_level": 2,
      children: []
    }
  ]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "ac",
  "parent_id": null,
  "value": 110,
  "tree_level": 1,
  children: []
}
```

Below is the code which I wrote to convert but it doesn't work for me. 
It is not creating children inside, instead creating it outside.

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    if (d.parent_id === null)
      return d;
  }).rollup(function(ele) {
    return ele.map(function(c) {
      return {
        "id": c.id,
        "parent_id": c.parent_id,
        "name": c.name,
        "logValue": c.logValue,
        "tree_level": c.tree_level
      };
    });
  }).entries(this.dataset);
console.log(nested)
```

will d3.nest() work or i need something else ?

Comment: please format your code and text

Comment: okay. I have done now. Does it helps now ?

Comment: surely your data and code have *indentation*

Comment: so d3.nest would help me or i have to use something called undescore.js for changing the format @Bravo ?

Comment: @Amir do you need to use d3 or can you use a recursive function?

Comment: No its not mandatory.Can use anything except external liabraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing that data to `d3.partition()`, which you'll use to create the sunburst, all you need is [`d3.stratify`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify). In your case:

```
const stratify = d3.stratify()
  .parentId(function(d) {
    return d.parent_id;
  });

const hierarchicalData = stratify(data);
```

Here is the demo (use your browser's console to see the object, not the S.O. snippet's one):

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 131567,
    "name": "cellular organisms",
    "tree_level": 1,
    "display_order": 2,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2759,
    "name": "Eukaryota",
    "tree_level": 2,
    "display_order": 5,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 131567
  },
  {
    "id": 33154,
    "name": "Opisthokonta",
    "tree_level": 3,
    "display_order": 49,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 2759
  }, {
    "id": 33208,
    "name": "Metazoa",
    "tree_level": 4,
    "display_order": 126,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 33154
  }, {
    "id": 6072,
    "name": "Eumetazoa",
    "tree_level": 5,
    "display_order": 227,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 33208
  }, {
    "id": 33213,
    "name": "Bilateria",
    "tree_level": 6,
    "display_order": 547,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 6072
  }, {
    "id": 33511,
    "name": "Deuterostomia",
    "tree_level": 7,
    "display_order": 950,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 33213
  }, {
    "id": 7711,
    "name": "Chordata",
    "tree_level": 8,
    "display_order": 1639,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 33511
  }, {
    "id": 89593,
    "name": "Craniata",
    "tree_level": 9,
    "display_order": 3042,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 7711
  }, {
    "id": 7742,
    "name": "Vertebrata",
    "tree_level": 10,
    "display_order": 3614,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 89593
  }, {
    "id": 7776,
    "name": "Gnathostomata",
    "tree_level": 11,
    "display_order": 4245,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 7742
  }, {
    "id": 117570,
    "name": "Teleostomi",
    "tree_level": 12,
    "display_order": 4684,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 7776
  }, {
    "id": 117571,
    "name": "Euteleostomi",
    "tree_level": 13,
    "display_order": 4994,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 117570
  }, {
    "id": 8287,
    "name": "Sarcopterygii",
    "tree_level": 14,
    "display_order": 5175,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 117571
  }, {
    "id": 1338369,
    "name": "Dipnotetrapodomorpha",
    "tree_level": 15,
    "display_order": 5787,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 8287
  }, {
    "id": 32523,
    "name": "Tetrapoda",
    "tree_level": 16,
    "display_order": 5945,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 1338369
  }, {
    "id": 32524,
    "name": "Amniota",
    "tree_level": 17,
    "display_order": 6322,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 32523
  }, {
    "id": 40674,
    "name": "Mammalia",
    "tree_level": 18,
    "display_order": 6556,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 32524
  }, {
    "id": 32525,
    "name": "Theria",
    "tree_level": 19,
    "display_order": 6705,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 40674
  }, {
    "id": 9347,
    "name": "Eutheria",
    "tree_level": 20,
    "display_order": 6882,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 32525
  }, {
    "id": 1437010,
    "name": "Boreoeutheria",
    "tree_level": 21,
    "display_order": 7254,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18314,
    "parent_id": 9347
  }, {
    "id": 314145,
    "name": "Laurasiatheria",
    "tree_level": 22,
    "display_order": 7469,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 48,
    "parent_id": 1437010
  }, {
    "id": 314146,
    "name": "Euarchontoglires",
    "tree_level": 22,
    "display_order": 7470,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 18281,
    "parent_id": 1437010
  }, {
    "id": 9443,
    "name": "Primates",
    "tree_level": 23,
    "display_order": 7575,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17686,
    "parent_id": 314146
  }, {
    "id": 33554,
    "name": "Carnivora",
    "tree_level": 23,
    "display_order": 7598,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 314145
  }, {
    "id": 91561,
    "name": "Cetartiodactyla",
    "tree_level": 23,
    "display_order": 7629,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 37,
    "parent_id": 314145
  }, {
    "id": 314147,
    "name": "Glires",
    "tree_level": 23,
    "display_order": 7675,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 314146
  }, {
    "id": 9845,
    "name": "Ruminantia",
    "tree_level": 24,
    "display_order": 7760,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 91561
  }, {
    "id": 9989,
    "name": "Rodentia",
    "tree_level": 24,
    "display_order": 7762,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 314147
  }, {
    "id": 35497,
    "name": "Suina",
    "tree_level": 24,
    "display_order": 7776,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 21,
    "parent_id": 91561
  }, {
    "id": 376913,
    "name": "Haplorrhini",
    "tree_level": 24,
    "display_order": 7857,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17686,
    "parent_id": 9443
  }, {
    "id": 379584,
    "name": "Caniformia",
    "tree_level": 24,
    "display_order": 7859,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 33554
  }, {
    "id": 9655,
    "name": "Mustelidae",
    "tree_level": 25,
    "display_order": 7931,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 379584
  }, {
    "id": 9821,
    "name": "Suidae",
    "tree_level": 25,
    "display_order": 7938,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 21,
    "parent_id": 35497
  }, {
    "id": 35500,
    "name": "Pecora",
    "tree_level": 25,
    "display_order": 7956,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 9845
  }, {
    "id": 314293,
    "name": "Simiiformes",
    "tree_level": 25,
    "display_order": 8029,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17686,
    "parent_id": 376913
  }, {
    "id": 1963758,
    "name": "Myomorpha",
    "tree_level": 25,
    "display_order": 8054,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 9989
  }, {
    "id": 9479,
    "name": "Platyrrhini",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8101,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 251,
    "parent_id": 314293
  }, {
    "id": 9526,
    "name": "Catarrhini",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8102,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 314293
  }, {
    "id": 9822,
    "name": "Sus",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8108,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 21,
    "parent_id": 9821
  }, {
    "id": 9895,
    "name": "Bovidae",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8112,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 35500
  }, {
    "id": 169418,
    "name": "Mustelinae",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8190,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 9655
  }, {
    "id": 337687,
    "name": "Muroidea",
    "tree_level": 26,
    "display_order": 8202,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 1963758
  }, {
    "id": 9665,
    "name": "Mustela",
    "tree_level": 27,
    "display_order": 8256,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 169418
  }, {
    "id": 9823,
    "name": "Sus scrofa",
    "tree_level": 27,
    "display_order": 8261,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 21,
    "parent_id": 9822
  }, {
    "id": 10066,
    "name": "Muridae",
    "tree_level": 27,
    "display_order": 8267,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 337687
  }, {
    "id": 27592,
    "name": "Bovinae",
    "tree_level": 27,
    "display_order": 8277,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 9895
  }, {
    "id": 314295,
    "name": "Hominoidea",
    "tree_level": 27,
    "display_order": 8339,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 9526
  }, {
    "id": 9604,
    "name": "Hominidae",
    "tree_level": 28,
    "display_order": 8386,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 314295
  }, {
    "id": 9668,
    "name": "Mustela putorius",
    "tree_level": 28,
    "display_order": 8389,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 9665
  }, {
    "id": 9903,
    "name": "Bos",
    "tree_level": 28,
    "display_order": 8395,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 27592
  }, {
    "id": 39107,
    "name": "Murinae",
    "tree_level": 28,
    "display_order": 8420,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 741,
    "parent_id": 10066
  }, {
    "id": 9669,
    "name": "Mustela putorius furo",
    "tree_level": 29,
    "display_order": 8545,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 11,
    "parent_id": 9668
  }, {
    "id": 9913,
    "name": "Bos taurus",
    "tree_level": 29,
    "display_order": 8547,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 16,
    "parent_id": 9903
  }, {
    "id": 10088,
    "name": "Mus",
    "tree_level": 29,
    "display_order": 8556,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 3,
    "parent_id": 39107
  }, {
    "id": 10114,
    "name": "Rattus",
    "tree_level": 29,
    "display_order": 8557,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 740,
    "parent_id": 39107
  }, {
    "id": 207598,
    "name": "Homininae",
    "tree_level": 29,
    "display_order": 8606,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 9604
  }, {
    "id": 9605,
    "name": "Homo",
    "tree_level": 30,
    "display_order": 8684,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 207598
  }, {
    "id": 9606,
    "name": "Homo sapiens",
    "tree_level": 31,
    "display_order": 8808,
    "has_data": "N",
    "is_leaf": "N",
    "value": 17435,
    "parent_id": 9605
  }
];

const stratify = d3.stratify()
  .parentId(function(d) {
    return d.parent_id;
  });

const hierarchicalData = stratify(data);

console.log(hierarchicalData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi it works for the json which i shared but for this json https://jsfiddle.net/6djrp2o7/ it gives an error as multiple roots. @Gerardo

Comment: That's because you can have only **one** root, that is, only one object with `parent_id` as `null`.

Comment: than how can i show this  json https://jsfiddle.net/6djrp2o7/ on sun burst

Comment: Please, do not ask questions in the comment section. If you have a new question, which is the case, post it as a question, with all relevant details. However, I'll say it again: your data must contain only **one** root.

Comment: If you see the sun burst object their can be multiple parents with  multiple children of their own. Sorry for asking in comment section

Comment: *"If you see the sun burst object their can be multiple parents with multiple children of their own"*. Yes, but just **one root**. I'm talking about the root, not about the parents/children. The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify_parentId) is very clear: ***"There must be exactly one root node in the input data, and no circular relationships."***.

Comment: Yes i understood what you are trying to say. Thanks alot man.